# is provisioning storage in VMAX difficult?

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, emc

is provisioning storage in VMAX difficult? I am not getting any sort of training from my manager .There's going to be requests fro the clients in provisioning storage to their hosts (cluster, stand alone) .
I have gone through few doc but there's not much information there.I request guys here to help me with a proper link ,if not the explanation ,on how to provision storage from VMAX.

I know many people here would have worked on VMAX and allocated storage. Please guide me as i am in desperate need.

Any link related to that will be greatly appreciated.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't too late, but provisioning storage is pretty easy on the VMAX.  A quick guide can be found [here](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2010/09/22/new-users-guide-to-symmetrix-vmax-auto-provisioning-groups-via-cli-part-1/).  In short, you'll need to create:

- A storage group that groups your devices
- A port group that groups your directors and ports
- An initiator group that contains your hosts and WWNs
- And a masking view, which ties your three groups together